# TCP packets out of order in Unity TCP client connection on Mac only

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, tcpclient

I have a Unity script which connects to a server using TCP. The server sends messages of arbitrary length. The length of the message is described in the first 4 bytes of the message, which I use to determine when the full message has arrived. For some reason, the message isn't being "stitched" together in the correct order. This problem, however, only occurs on Mac. The same script works perfectly fine on Windows (same version of Unity too). Any idea?

Unity version: 2018.4.19f

The connection code is as follows (I edited out things for simplicity of the question):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class ServerConnection : MonoBehaviour {
    // Example connection parameters
    public string IP = "192.168.0.10"; 
    public int Port = 8085;

    /// The task object where TCP connection runs.
    Task ServerTask { get; set; }

    TcpClient Client { get; set; }
    Socket Socket { get; set; }
    string Message { get; set; }

    /// Gets called on the push of a button
    public void Connect() {
        ServerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(listenForDataAsync, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    async private void listenForDataAsync() {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Connecting to server: IP={0}, Port={1}", IP, Port));
        try {
            Client = new TcpClient(IP, Port);
            Debug.Log("Connection established");

            byte[] message = new byte[0];
            byte[] msgSize = new byte[4];
            int messageSize = 0;
            using (NetworkStream stream = Client.GetStream()) {
                while (true) {
                    // Wait for 4 bytes to get message size
                    await stream.ReadAsync(msgSize, 0, 4);

                    // Convert message size byte array to an int
                    int totalMessageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(msgSize, 0);
                
                    // subtract 4 from total message size (4 bytes previously read)
                    messageSize = totalMessageSize - 4;

                    // Wait for the rest of the message
                    message = new byte[messageSize];
                    int readBytes = 0;
                    while (messageSize != 0) {
                        readBytes = await stream.ReadAsync(message, readBytes, messageSize);
                        messageSize -= readBytes;
                    }

                    // Decode byte array to string
                    string response = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(message);

                    // On Mac, response has the message out of order. 
                    // On Windows, it is always perfectly fine.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** The server is implemented in C++ using Qt and is running on a Windows machine. The server sends responses that may contain large chunks of data. The entire message is composed of 4 bytes indicating the length of the whole message followed by the response itself. The response is a Json string. The error I'm getting is that the final string obtained from the code above is not ordered the same way as it was when it was sent. The message ends in `}` (closing the outer Json object). However, in the received response, after the `}`, there are tons of other values that were supposed to be part of an an array inside the Json object. To give you an example, take the following response sent by the server:

```
{data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
```

The code above gets something like:

```
{data: [0, 1, 2]}, 3, 4, 5, 7
```

This only happens when the responses are starting to hit the kilobytes range (and higher), and I emphasize, the exact same code works perfectly fine on Windows.

The server sends the message in the following way:

```
// The response in Json
QJsonObject responseJson;

// Convert to byte array
QJsonDocument doc(responseJson);
QByteArray message = doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::JsonFormat::Compact);

// Insert 4 bytes indicating length of message
qint32 messageSize = sizeof(qint32) + message.size();
message.insert(0, (const char*)&messageSize, sizeof(qint32));

// Send message
// In here, socket is a QTcpSocket
socket->write(message);
```

**Edit #2** Here is an image of the output. The values after the `}` should have been part of the big array right before `Message`.

[image]

Comment: One thing I'd be wary of - you correctly loop to receive the body of the message - but you assume you'll always get the 4 bytes describing the length in one go. That assumption can also be unsound.

Comment: I've thought about this before, but I figure the first packet is unlikely to be less than 4 bytes (or is it?). I guess I could go 1 byte at a time to be safe, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: TCP doesn't deliver data out of order. Not even on a Mac. You have a bug in the code somewhere, and _any_ assumption you make about which bytes are delivered together is a completely invalid assumption. TCP guarantees only that the bytes will be delivered in sequence, nothing else. Any time you fail to check the byte count for a read operation, your code is wrong and needs to be fixed. If you are already sending data as text, then you might find it preferable to use `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` and let the line breaks be your data delimiters. If you want to read binary data, take a ...

Comment: ... look at `BinaryReader`, as it encapsulates logic for reading all the necessary bytes for a given type of data (but be careful about its string handling...it uses an unusual scheme for encoding strings).

Comment: All that said, your question is too vague to provide an actual answer. You need to provide a [mcve] which when networking is involved means both endpoints of the connection, and you need to be clearer about what the problem is. "Out of order" could mean anything. You need to explain _precisely_ what the code does, and how that's different from what you expected.

Comment: Can you show an example of the expected output on Windows vs. what you're getting on Mac? Also: What platform is the server running on?

Comment: I will look into `StreamReader`, `StreamWriter`, and `BinaryReader`. I have edited the post with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any time you see `Read`/`ReadAsync` without capturing and using the result: the code is simply wrong.

Fortunately, it isn't a *huge* fix:

```cs
int toRead = 4, offset = 0, read;
while (toRead != 0 && (read = stream.ReadAsync(msgSize, offset, toRead)) > 0)
{
    offset += read;
    toRead -= read;
}
if (toRead != 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
```

As a side note: `BitConverter.ToInt32` is dangerous - it assumes CPU endianness, which *is not fixed*. It would be better to use `BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian` or `BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the `BinaryPrimitives`. I do plan to change how I receive the first 4 bytes since I can't assume all 4 will arrive at once. However, what you suggested does not address my issue.

Comment: @Velchivz you might also want to check your offset logic in the second read loop and compare/contrast: `stream.ReadAsync(message, readBytes, messageSize);` looks wrong too (the offset should be strictly increasing, not jumping around to whatever the last read returned). Beyond that, you're going to have to add logging. You're asking us to remotely debug network code without access to the network bytes

Comment: Got it! You are correct on the offset. It was weird because this worked on Windows. Any idea why that was the case?

Comment: @Velchivz it was working by accident, probably due to different buffer sizes in the network stack; but the code was still broken and it *would* have failed on Windows eventually